# Ember Bind Attr

Tags: ember.js

What I am trying to achieve here is that I have an image tag and a browse button. When the user uploads an image I show the image in that window. But I am trying to use bind-attr so that whenever the user changes the images the src is updated. Here is my code for image tag. `<img {{bind-attr src=imgUrl}}/>` Now in the controller I am changing the value of imgUrl so that it updates it in the frontend as well. But it isn't replacing the old url. I mean it keeps the url which is uploaded the first time.
Any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding it properly, but you're probably out of scope (aka `imgUrl` on the controller isn't the `imgUrl` that was bound to the img tag)

Here's an example of it working.  If you can't find the mistake, feel free to replicate using this jsbin.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/filor/1/edit

Comment: The thing is I have that foo variable in my controller but when I am trying to update in the action of my Controller then its not updating it. This is my code  
 <img {{bind-attr src=imgUrl}}/>
 and this is my controller
 Cards.SelectImageController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  url: null,
  selectedValuesGlobal: null,
  inkBlobGlobal: null,
  jcrop_api: null,
  w: null,
  h: null,
  imgUrl: 'images/icons/tablet_postcard_front_blank.png',
  actions: {

   openImagesToUpload: function ()
   {
   imgUrl = the uploaded image path here
     
But then the imgUrl isn't updating.

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/havopivo/1/edit Maybe you see here what I am trying to do. i am not sure if it is even possible.

Comment: You need to use set in order for ember to know you've changed the value.

Comment: sorry I got it. I was missing quotes.